# MongoDB error :An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Tags: mongodb

I have installed mongodb recently and when I try to run it I am getting this error. Can anyone help me with this error?

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin>mongo.exe
MongoDB shell version v3.6.2
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2018-01-29T11:53:16.025+0530 I NETWORK  [thread1] Socket recv() An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine. 127.0.0.1:27017
2018-01-29T11:53:16.025+0530 I NETWORK  [thread1] SocketException: remote: (NONE):0 error: SocketException socket exception [RECV_ERROR] server [127.0.0.1:27017]
2018-01-29T11:53:16.026+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: network error while attempting to run command 'isMaster' on host '127.0.0.1:27017'  :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:251:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

Comment: Even I got the same set of errors when I run 'mongo' on another terminal.

Comment: Additional error : On the terminal where I run mongod the error is  Error: network error while attempting to run command 'isMaster' on host '127.0.0.1:27017'

Answer (score 0):

Open `mongod` from this path

> C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin

then run `mongo` from another terminal.